How to combine Date and Integer with Python sqlalchemy?
def getBeforePoint(userId, endDate=None):
    today = datetime.now().date()

    subquery = (
        db.session.query(
            T_user_point.user_promotion_code_id,
            T_user_point.acquired_at,
            M_promotion_code.valid_days,
            T_user_promotion_code.promotion_code_id
        )
        .join(T_user_promotion_code, T_user_point.user_promotion_code_id == T_user_promotion_code.user_promotion_code_id)
        .join(M_promotion_code, T_user_promotion_code.promotion_code_id == M_promotion_code.promotion_code_id)
        .subquery()
    )
    subquery2 = (
        db.session.query(
            T_user_point.user_promotion_code_id,
            T_user_point.acquired_at,
            M_promotion_code.valid_days,
            T_user_promotion_code.promotion_code_id
        )
        .join(T_user_promotion_code, T_user_point.user_promotion_code_id == T_user_promotion_code.user_promotion_code_id)
        .join(M_promotion_code, T_user_promotion_code.promotion_code_id == M_promotion_code.promotion_code_id)
        .first()
    )

    # Get valid_days as an integer
    valid_days = db.session.query(subquery.c.valid_days).filter(
        subquery.c.user_promotion_code_id == T_user_point.user_promotion_code_id,
        subquery.c.user_promotion_code_id == T_user_promotion_code.user_promotion_code_id,
        subquery.c.promotion_code_id == M_promotion_code.promotion_code_id
    ).as_scalar()

    point = (
        db.session.query(func.sum(T_user_point.point))
        .join(subquery, T_user_point.user_promotion_code_id == subquery.c.user_promotion_code_id)
        .filter(
            *(
                [
                    T_user_point.user_id == userId,
                    T_user_point.is_deleted == False,
                    # Get points whose acquisition date + expiration date is less than today.
                    subquery.c.acquired_at + cast(valid_days, Integer) >= today
                ] if valid_days is not None else [
                    T_user_point.user_id == userId,
                    T_user_point.acquired_at <= endDate,
                    T_user_point.is_deleted == False
                ]
            )
        )
        .scalar()
    )

    if point is None:
        return 0

    return point

of the above code
subquery.c.acquired_at + cast(valid_days, Integer) >= today
this part is not working but I can’t see the error.
I'm having trouble getting points.
subquery.c.acquired_at + cast(valid_days, Integer) >= today
How can I check this code works or not?
I tried
print(subquery.c.acquired_at + cast(valid_days, Integer)) 

and get
anon_1.acquired_at + CAST((SELECT anon_1.valid_days 

I don't know what means

Date and time arithmetic tends to be different for each RDBMS. Which RDBMS are you using?

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5672
